# How to list EC2 security group *rules* from within instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, groups

I have SSH root access to an EC2 instance but no access to the AWS Console / AWS KEY & SECRET.

My incoming traffic to this host on all TCP ports except 22 TCP seems to be blocked - I cannot access my services (for example `nginx` on port 80) from the outside.

`nmap` shows these ports as `filtered`, while port 22 is shown as open when SSH is running and `closed` when SSH is temporarily shut down.

ICMP and UDP are also blocked.

(I used `ping`, `nc` and some other tools to check that.)

I know that my instance is in some custom, non-default EC2 Security Group named, let's say `my-security-group`, but I don't know its rules.

**How to list these rules with the access level I have got?**

**Update 1:** My `iptables` rules are empty - let's assume that I am sure that its the Security Group that is blocking my traffic.

Comment: You can't. You can get a list of groups you're in at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups` but it won't give you the rules.

Comment: @ceejayoz You should make this comment an answer. I will upvote it soon as it looks like you are right. :( (Sorry to be sad about it.)

Comment: Done, thanks! Sorry I don't have a better answer for ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can get a list of groups you're in at `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/security-groups` but it won't give you the rules themselves.