# How to detect what's blocking my incoming traffic on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, if it's NOT iptables and NOT EC2 Security Group?

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, ubuntu-14.04

I have SSH root access to an EC2 instance.

It's Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have `nginx` web server listening on all interfaces on port 80 TCP. It's accessible from this server but not from the outside.

Apparently all of my incoming traffic except 22 TCP is blocked - other TCP ports, all UDP and ICMP.

Yet my `iptables` on this server are empty:

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# iptables -v -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3162 packets, 1472K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4203 packets, 674K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Here's the `nmap` scan output from my local machine:

```
grzegorz@MacBook-Pro-Grzegorz:~$ sudo nmap -v -Pn -p 22,80 x.x.x.x

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-01-31 20:40 CET
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 20:40
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 20:40, 0.16s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 20:40
Scanning ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x) [2 ports]
Discovered open port 22/tcp on 54.93.91.112
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 20:40, 1.38s elapsed (2 total ports)
Nmap scan report for ec2-x-x-x-x.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.035s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp open     ssh
80/tcp filtered http

Read data files from: /usr/local/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.58 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 3 (132B) | Rcvd: 1 (44B)
```

..so some kind of firewall **is** blocking my traffic.

Let's assume that it's **NOT** an EC2 Security Group.

**What else can be blocking my traffic? Something that is running on the VPS itself? Something in the kernel or something in the user space?**

**UPDATE**:

I tested apparmor:

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# apparmor_status --verbose
apparmor module is loaded.
4 profiles are loaded.
4 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
1 processes have profiles defined.
1 processes are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient (607) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

..and I interpret this output as it hadn't anything to do with the filtering but I have disabled it anyway:

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# service apparmor stop
 * Clearing AppArmor profiles cache
   ...done.
All profile caches have been cleared, but no profiles have been unloaded.
Unloading profiles will leave already running processes permanently
unconfined, which can lead to unexpected situations.

To set a process to complain mode, use the command line tool
'aa-complain'. To really tear down all profiles, run the init script
with the 'teardown' option."
root@ip-x-x-x-x:~# service apparmor teardown
 * Unloading AppArmor profiles
   ...done.
```

..but it didn't help. `nmap` still shows `filtered` TCP 80, `nginx` still not accessible.

Comment: You should look at your EC2 security group.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's AWS EC2 instance but this should not matter as I am asking about firewall **on the server itself**. But I have added this info to my question to prevent the further downvoting..

Comment: Then the answer is no.

Comment: Are you actually trying to solve a problem? Why haven't you checked your security group?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I don't have access to it - see http://serverfault.com/questions/663843/how-to-list-ec2-security-group-rules-from-within-instance

Comment: It's kind of a test problem.

Comment: Did you have app-armor installed and running?
Try also wireshark for see blocked packets or something bad on network traffic

Comment: Yes, but it didn't filter any traffic. I will update my question with info about it.

Comment: You need to find out who _does_ have access to the security group, then. Everything else is just wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the hosting provider have a firewall service defaulting to only permit ssh traffic to the server. The purpose of such a default could be to limit exposure of the server until you have had time to install all security updates, harden your configuration, and in general ensure your server is ready to go live.

If such a service happens to be in place, there is likely going to exist a web interface through which it can be configured. There should also exist a place to disable it completely.

The steps I would recommend are the following:

1. Read documentation from the hosting provider to find out if a firewall service like the one described above happens to be in place.
2. Use tools to narrow down the location of any filters you haven't found documentation for.
3. Ask the provider

What you can do to narrow down the location of filters is to use the `traceroute` command. Ubuntu 14.04 has a `traceroute` command with flags that can send packets with specific protocol and port number. That way you can for example compare the output obtained from a trace to port 22 and port 80.

```
traceroute -n -T -p 22 server
```

Notice that different `traceroute` implementations exist. If for some reason the flags seem not to work, then try `traceroute.db`, which should give you the version with support for the above combination of flags.

Comment: Thank you but the whole provider firewall part does not answer my question - see the "apart from external firewall" part.

Comment: I also already used `traceroute`, `tcptraceroute`, `nmap` and some other tools already and I am (pretty) sure that something is blocking my incoming traffic. The question that I am asking is: **what** is blocking it?

Comment: @GrzegorzDubicki Depends on what you mean by blocked. If TCP connections to port 22 work and TCP connections to port 80 get a RST, it simply means nothing is listening on port 80. If connections to port 22 work and SYN packets to port 80 are silently dropped, it has to be some kind of firewall, which is causing it. Notice that iptables is not the only firewall which could be used on a Linux machine. Also, have you actually verified that the host is receiving SYN packets in the first place?

Comment: @GrzegorzDubicki Have you compared traceroute output, like I suggested?

Comment: "Notice that iptables is not the only firewall which could be used on a Linux machine" - **that's what I am asking here. What are these other kinds of firewalls?** For what I know all others are some kind of `iptables` frontends (like `ufw`)..

Comment: I have done `nmap` TCP SYN scan which clearly says that traffic to port 80 TCP is filtered (I used word "blocked" in a comment before in a not very precise way - I meant "filtered"). I will add it's output to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no other firewall solution on Linux that doesn't in fact use `iptables/netfilter`. Also a simple SYN test is the proper way to check if your traffic is filtered by a firewall. You are right that looking for an "upstream" firewall, a Security Group of this EC2 instance in this example, is the only reasonable way to resolve this. Thank you for all your input that led to this answer.